# Showing Canvas Outside UserControl boundary

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, popup

I've found several threads on various sites vaguely related this, but no solid answers.

Here's a simplified example: I want to create a usercontrol that has a textbox and a small icon beside it.  If you click the image, I want to have a canvas appear under the control that has information in it.  The canvas would be outside the usercontrol's boundary.

I have gotten this "sorta" working.  If I put the textbox, graphic, and just a canvas on the control, with the canvas outside the clip of the usercontrol - I can make the canvas visible/invisible as desired.

When I add stackpanels and such, it starts exhibiting odd behavior - sometime simply vanishing.

So, here's the question - what is the right way to do this?  Or, is there a "right way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is put your canvas into a `<Popup>` control. then, show the popup when needed.  [Here](http://www.silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-samples/silverlight-popup-sample-37378/) is a video showing how to use a `<Popup>` control, [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is the MSDN documentation.